# PHP Save file on client's device

Tags: php

How can I save a file with a string on the client's device using php?

```
$handle = fopen("newfile.txt", "w+");

$txt = "string";

$content = fwrite($handle, $txt);
```

Answer (score 0):

Think that you actually cannot write files on the client's device, but you could follow this steps to have a similar result.

1. Write a file with the string you want on the server side
2. Download the file
3. Delete the file from server

Hope this helps